# How to add admin user in airflow?

Tags: airflow

How to add admin user in airflow ?

I want to use simple **Web Authentication**.
If I add user as described in documentation [airflow.apache.ort/security](http://airflow.apache.org/security.html#web-authentication) then user is not an admin.

code from docs:

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'new_user_name'
user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
user.password = 'set_the_password'
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you are using the `rbac` UI, the easiest option is to run the following command for **Airflow <2** :

```sh
airflow create_user \
    --email EMAIL --firstname firstname \
    --lastname lastname --password password \
    --role Admin --username username
```

For **Airflow > 2**:

```sh
airflow users create \
    --email EMAIL --firstname firstname \
    --lastname lastname --password password \
    --role Admin --username username
```

Comment: `airflow command error: argument GROUP_OR_COMMAND: `airflow create_user` command, has been removed, please use `airflow users create`, see help above.`

Answer (score 5):

I found that models.User() have **superuser** property [airflow.apache.org/_modules](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/1.10.14/_modules/airflow/models/user.html)
and I simply set that property True:

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'new_user_name'
user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
user.password = 'set_the_password'
user.superuser = True
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

Answer (score 1):

also dont forget to set your AIRFLOW_HOME var when running the add user script, otherwise it will create user into a sqlite db, not your actual DB

add_user.py

```
import airflow
from airflow import models, settings
from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
user = PasswordUser(models.User())
user.username = 'admin'
user.email = 'admin@company.com'
user.password = 'pw123'
user.superuser = True
session = settings.Session()
session.add(user)
session.commit()
session.close()
exit()
```

create user

```
export AIRFLOW_HOME=/path/to/your/airflow

source venv/bin/activate

(airflow) python add_user.py
```

Answer (score 0):

If anyone is looking a way that is easy to understand then here's the thing.

Activate you airflow python environment and start python shell. Then with the help of these commands you can easily set a new user in airflow.

```
>>> import airflow
>>> from airflow import models, settings
>>> from airflow.contrib.auth.backends.password_auth import PasswordUser
>>> user = PasswordUser(models.User())
>>> user.username = 'new_user_name'
>>> user.email = 'new_user_email@example.com'
>>> user.password = 'set_the_password'
>>> user.superuser = True
>>> session = settings.Session()
>>> session.add(user)
>>> session.commit()
>>> session.close()
>>> exit()
```

Answer (score 0):

**Airflow 2.0+**

```
airflow users create --role Admin --username x \
--firstname y \
--lastname z \
--email m \
--password n
```

You can do this from terminal anywhere, as long as you set the environment variable pointing to your airflow db backend (given its reachable from your terminal)

```
AIRFLOW__CORE__SQL_ALCHEMY_CONN
```

and obviously airflow installed

```
pip3 install apache-airflow[postgres]
```

assuming you are using a postgres backend, you can just install apache-airflow if you are using sqlite.

Answer (score 0):

Use the below command to create the admin user as per latest documentation from Apache airflow

```sh
$ airflow users create -e EMAIL -f firstname -l lastname -p password -r Admin -u username
```

Apache airflow documentation [link](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/cli-and-env-variables-ref.html#create_repeat1)

Answer (score 0):

For anyone looking to do this in python code in Airflow 2, you'll no longer be able to use PasswordUser like you could in Airflow 1 (it's no longer there)

I had a custom auth class I was using and when upgrading to Airflow 2 I had to remove all references to PasswordUser and simply use

```
init_app(_):
    """Initializes authentication backend"""
```

Which is what they do for the basic auth class: https://github.com/apache/airflow/blob/v2-1-stable/airflow/api/auth/backend/basic_auth.py

Airflow 2 handled the rest for me as far as dashboard users go.